# os to remove files with Python (trying to removed from multiple file directories)

Tags: python

I'm still very new to Python so I'm trying to apply Python in to my own situation for some experience
One useful program is to delete files, in this case by file type from a directory

```
import os
target = "H:\\documents\\"

for x in os.listdir(target):
    if x.endswith(".rtf"):
        os.unlink(target + x)
```

Taking this program, I have tried to expand it to delete ost files in every local profiles:

```
import os

list = []
folder = "c:\\Users"

for subfolder in os.listdir(folder):
    list.append(subfolder)

ost_folder = "c:\\users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook"

for users in list:
    ost_list = os.listdir(ost_folder%users)
    for file in ost_list:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            print(file)
```

This should be printing the file name but spits an error that the file directory cannot be found

Comment: Side-note: Don't name your variables `list`; by doing so at global scope, you've cut off access to the `list` constructor for your entire script starting at the line `list = []`.

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: For me it dies with user "All Users", as it has never run Outlook, and in particular it doesn't even have an AppData folder. In alphabetical order the next two would be "Default" and "Default User", which would die too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every folder under `C:\Users` will have a `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` subdirectory (there are typically hidden directories there that you may not see in Windows Explorer that don't correspond to a real user, and have never run Outlook, so they don't have that folder at all, but will be found by `os.listdir`); when you call `os.listdir` on such a directory, it dies with the exception you're seeing. Skip the directories that don't have it. The simplest way to do so is to have [the `glob` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) do the work for you (which avoids the need for your first loop entirely):

```
import glob
import os

for folder in glob.glob(r"c:\users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook"):
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            print(os.path.join(folder, file))
```

You can simplify it even further by pushing *all* the work to `glob`:

```
for txtfile in glob.glob(r"c:\users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.txt"):
    print(txtfile)
```

Or do the more modern OO-style `pathlib` alternative:

```
for txtfile in pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users').glob(r'*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.txt'):
    print(txtfile)
```